# Fetching a unique Row Based on a unique value of a column MySQL

Tags: mysql

I Am trying to figure out the a query to achieve a output for the following scenario, below is my table data

[image: table entries]

Id -> primary key table1 
Request id -> FK (PK of table2)

Id -> Many to One -> Request id column

Question:
I will be getting the SID column values(LIST -> can be one or more values) from the UI, Now suppose I am getting a list ('121','122'), I should be getting the below result, [image: query result]

Explanation:
1. Row with Id -> 3,4,5,6,7 is not needed since I need only the rows which has combination of SID(121,122)

2. Suppose I am getting a list of SID as ('121') , then the result should be as below,[image: query result 2] even though there other entries which has 121 in SID but they have same Request Id which is present in other rows as well ..

so bottom line is I M trying to get Request id which has only the combination of SIDs .. if SID list has 2 values then i want the rows with same Request id and at the same time the Request id shouldnt be present in another SID apart from the list.

I am stuck with this query for past 2 days, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: SQlFiddle -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98484b/1

Comment: It's really unhelpful to put images of your data in your question. Why? Because we answerers sometimes try to use http://sqlfiddle.com to reproduce your problem. But we won't try it if we have to type your data again. Please [edit] your question. Your best bet to get answers is to create the sqlfiddle yourself.

Comment: I have updated my question with the fiddle link .. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE TABLE T(ID INT,REQUESTID INT, SID INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T VALUES
    -> (1,1,121),(2,1,122),
    -> (3,2,121),(4,3,123),
    -> (5,3,121),(6,3,125),
    -> (7,3,126),(8,4,121),
    -> (9,4,122);
Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT T.ID,S.* FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT REQUESTID ,GROUP_CONCAT(ID),GROUP_CONCAT(SID ORDER BY SID) SID
    -> FROM T
    -> GROUP BY REQUESTID
    -> ) S
    -> JOIN T ON T.REQUESTID = S.REQUESTID
    -> WHERE S.SID = '121,122';
+------+-----------+------------------+---------+
| ID   | REQUESTID | GROUP_CONCAT(ID) | SID     |
+------+-----------+------------------+---------+
|    1 |         1 | 1,2              | 121,122 |
|    2 |         1 | 1,2              | 121,122 |
|    8 |         4 | 8,9              | 121,122 |
|    9 |         4 | 8,9              | 121,122 |
+------+-----------+------------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT T.ID,S.* FROM
    -> (
    -> SELECT REQUESTID ,GROUP_CONCAT(ID),GROUP_CONCAT(SID ORDER BY SID) SID
    -> FROM T
    -> GROUP BY REQUESTID
    -> ) S
    -> JOIN T ON T.REQUESTID = S.REQUESTID
    -> WHERE S.SID = '121';
+------+-----------+------------------+------+
| ID   | REQUESTID | GROUP_CONCAT(ID) | SID  |
+------+-----------+------------------+------+
|    3 |         2 | 3                | 121  |
+------+-----------+------------------+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```